# MagicalRecord SQLite file empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am having problem reading a file. I'm using MagicalRecord as my CoreData wrapper. I successfully save or update object. With my NSLog I can see it, everything is fine and I can use it in my database. But every time I want to see SQLite file with my application (I'm using Datum LE), file is empty. I cannot access that file directly within my Library folder in my app. I copy that file to my desktop and it is empty. What am I doing wrong? So once more, everything inside my iOS application works fine, I can see records being saved and I can fetch them normally.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Where is the file when you attempt to update it?  In the app bundle or the documents/caches/application support directory?

Comment: add some code snippets where this problem is triggered

Comment: In my iOS siulator device folder, Data Application Library Application Support

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly looking at the wrong file. If your app is saving (I assume, across app restarts), the date is *definitely* saved.

One way to find out is to `NSLog` the persistent store URL and check the referenced file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are encountering is the new default journaling mode that Core Data uses.

See this article
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1809/_index.html

Basically your changes are not written to the `.sqlite` file, but are found in `.sqlite-wal`. HOWEVER, most SQLite reading apps I have tried blow away the `-wal` when you open the `.sqlite`, so good luck.

You could try changing the journaling mode for debugging purposes